# git clone overwrote an existing repo with the same name

Tags: git, recovery, rollback

it had a existing git checkout and had made some modifications, then i checked out the same repo and it overwrote the folder. Is there some way to get the old repos with the uncommitted changes?

I had checked " git reflog --all " but it only gave me the most recent checkout.

EDIT: cannot reproduce the issue. so guessing i made a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would happen with a `git checkout -f`
(`--force`: When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away local changes)

But it shouldn' be the case with a `git clone` on the same repo:

```
fatal: destination path 'myrepo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

If you did a `git checkout -f`, any changes added or private (not yet added) will be lost.

Comment: My guess is the title is a mistake, and this is all the result of an attempt to carry over "check out" from the centralized VCS world...

Comment: ok these are the steps:
1) git clone <repo>  
2) cd <repo>  
3) <make local modifications but do not commit them>  
4) cd ..  
5) git clone <branch-of-repo1>  
6) now, the <repo> folder gets overwritten  

what i should have done is checkout a remote but i did not do that :-)

Comment: @deepak: that is strange because: a/ `git clone <branch-of-repo1>` doesn't exist as a valid syntax. b/ any clone of any sort in an non-empty directory will be canceled (see my error message in my answer)

Comment: i cannot reproduce it again. Previously i had done a 'git pull' and had got an error. Will comment if i can recreate the issue. Thanks.